# Why will nmap not update for me?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, nmap

I'm currently running nmap 6.25 on Mac OSX 10.8.5. I tried to download the pre-compiled DMG bundle for 6.40 and install it. After installation it still shows me I have 6.25:

```
hehe~ ➙ nmap -V

Nmap version 6.25 ( http://nmap.org )
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Compiled with: liblua-5.2.1 openssl-1.0.1e libpcre-8.32 libpcap-1.3.0 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: kqueue poll select
```

I even tried compiling 6.40 from source and installing that way, but it is still gives me the same result. How can I get nmap to update, or to show as updated?

Comment: Please don't deface your question. If you want to delete it, just click on the `delete` link under the question.